# Как вывести массив

Tags: php, html

Скрипт,собирающий статистику о посещениях сайта.Нужно вывести город и страну.Вместо этого в переменной $entry_line выдает array в таблице

```
    <?php
    function countryCityFromIP($ipAddr)
    {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


    $url = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=c28b69b0c7cb56b5d876f24a22529b43f9371d72bbf860e56f80a859dea1b878&ip=$ip&form
    at=json";
    $d = file_get_contents($url);
    return json_decode($d , true);
    }
    $ip=countryCityFromIP($_REQUEST['ip']);
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $dtime = date("F j, Y, g:i:s ");
    if($uri == "/ip.php"){
    $uri = "Зашел на сайт";
    }
    echo "<p style='color:red;'>".$ip['cityName']."</p>";
    echo "<p style='color:red;'>".$ip['countryName']."</p>";
    $entry_line = "
    <center><table><tr><th><b>$dtime </b></th><th><b>$ip['cityName']</b>
    </th>
    <th><b> $uri </b></th></tr></table></center>
    ";

    $fp = fopen("admin/admin.php", "a");
    fputs($fp, $entry_line);
    fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$entry_line = "
<center><table><tr><th><b>$dtime </b></th><th><b>".$ip['cityName']."</b>
</th>
<th><b> $uri </b></th></tr></table></center>
";
```